# How do I load downloaded save files?

Tags: emulation, my-boy

I have the GBA emulator "My Boy!" (full version) for Android, and I am playing Pokemon Leaf Green. I downloaded some save files from gamefaqs.com and would like to know how to use them with the emulator.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 3, in case that makes a difference.

How do I use .sps file in the emulator? I can't load it.

Comment: I'll put this in a comment instead of an answer since I'm not 100% on this, but usually once you run a rom it creates it's own save file. Run the rom once and save. Stop the emulator and locate the save file in the directory (it's usually in the same place as the rom), take the save file you want to use and overwrite the save file you just made.

Answer (score 6):

To use a downloaded save file, you must rename the sav to have the same name as the ROM. I.E: *poke.gba* will load *poke.sav*. You must also set the cartridge save type in the emulator options to be the same as the sav file.

Answer (score 3):

In "My Boy!," .sav files are actually hidden in the same folders as the roms themselves. The only way that I found to show these files was to use the Android app "ASTRO File Manager." This app can go to the rom folders and see the hidden .sav files.

I would just use ASTRO to copy the .sav files into another folder, which removes whatever property makes them hidden. Then you can do whatever you want to the files and put them back into the folders they came from. Afterwards, the .sav files will always be visible and "My Boy!" will use them.

Answer (score 1):

Load the game in Visual Boy Advance, then Import->gameshark and load the game, then export it like export->battery file. Just find the file (.sav and .sg1 file) in the folder where your ROM is. Then transfer and rename the .sav file in your folder. I hope this will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its actually quite hard and confusing but I figured it out.
Follow my steps exactly:

1. First you need to run the gba file and save **in game**.
2. Download a save of the internet, it cannot be .SAV or any other type. It has to be .sav with no caps.
3. Locate your saves folder for my boy through a file editor app (ASTRO) `internalstorage/simcard->myboy->saves`.
4. Delete your .sav file and replace it with the save you downloaded off the internet with the same name, filetype etc.
5. Run your game and there should be an option to play your downloaded save!
   If this does not work, repeat. If it still does not work try downloading a different version of your gba file.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using Google Drive sync, the steps were a bit different for me. Here's what worked:

1. Open MyBoy
2. Make sure in Settings, Misc, "Sync to Google Drive" is enabled.
3. Play your game on MyBoy and save it.
4. Refresh Google Drive and make sure you see the new save file.
5. Drag your downloaded save file into your Google Drive folder. Make sure you select "Replace existing file". **(It will not work if you delete the old save and then upload the new one.)**
6. In MyBoy, tap the cloud icon to force it to retrieve new saves from Google Drive. It should say something like "1 file retrieved".
7. Now your MyBoy is synced up with Google Drive and you can play normally.

Answer (score -1):

just open my boy (paid) click on your rom and select continue if you have already saved. If you haven't, run your rom click on the top right and select save. Exit out of the rom the select continue then there's your progress.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking for.